# Facing problems while updating status using php sdk

Tags: php, image, facebook-graph-api

I use following code to update the status:

```
$parameters = array(
'message' => "Hey guys check this cool app",
'link' => "http://apps.facebook.com/xxxx",
'name' => "Invitation for xxxx",
'picture'=>"http://localhost:55/xxxx/logo.jpg",
'caption' => "Try xxxx!",
'access_token'=>$at //valid access token
);

try{
    $statusUpdate = $facebook->api('/me/feed', 'POST', $parameters);
}catch(FacebookApiException $e){}
```

This works and after status update, I get an id. But when i go to my profile and check the status update, This is what I see:
[image]. The problems are: (1) Image is not displayed, and (2) Unwanted `My first app` as shown in figure. Why is this happening? How do i fix it?

Answer (score 1):

1. `http://localhost/...` is never going to work as the image location because Facebook won't be able to retrieve it. Put the publicly accessible URL to the image in that field instead.
2. In the screenshot you posted, the 'My first app' part is the name of the app, you can change this in the app settings. It can't be changed on a per-post basis, all posts from your app are attributed to your app

Comment: Thanks for the first one. It worked.And no `My first app` is not part of my app. I checked my app settings too. There is nothing I can figure out about this problem. Any more Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

As far as the image is concerned, check again that the path of the image is correct. If it still does not work, try specifying 'https' instead of http and see what happens